# I can't get members from a 16k member server, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get certain user objects from a discord server using their IDs, but it can't get the guild object for some reason. My code:

```
@botclient.event
async def on_ready():
    for x in all_ids:
        guild = botclient.get_guild(GUILD)
        user=guild.get_member(x)
        all_urls[x]=user.avatar_url

botclient.run(TOKEN)
```

[TOKEN and GUILD are specified further above, I've checked multiple times and there seems to be nothing wrong with them]

It's worked in a smaller server before and I've tried several variations of this, but each gave me an AttributeError:

```
    user=guild.get_member(x)    
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member'
```

(sometimes this would also happen when trying to get the avatar URLs)

I enabled logging and after the exception, it would output(I've removed the guild ID)

```
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.
INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 107 members in guild ID -.
```

..which led me to believe that it actually succeeded at getting the guild, but for some reason it did not work in the code

I couldn't find any documentation on this, if anyone could point out where to find it/point out any mistakes I made that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like getting the guild fails at some point.  Try moving the `guild=...` line outside the loop

Comment: @PatrickHaugh tried that, still gives me a

`Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rev\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Documents\Python Documents\bot\test.py", line 23, in on_ready
    all_urls[x]=user.avatar_url
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'`

and then continues with all the

`INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the bot to the server?

After testing a bit it seems you can't get that data without the bot being allowed access to the server. If not, add it and then try again, that should work.

EDIT

```
@bot.command()
async def getMembers(ctx):
    members = ctx.guild.members

    print(members[:10])
```

Comment: It's in the server though, it shows up as online when I run the program. Could this be perms related? I thought bots wouldn't need any to be able to get members.
Afaik the bot only has the see channels perm.

Comment: Hmm no, just tested and my bot was able to do it just fine with only see channel permissions. Try running the command that I added to my answer and see if that returns anything.

Comment: When running that, it doesn't print anything, logs just show the
`INFO:discord.state:Processed a chunk for 1000 members in guild ID -.` (etc.)
again

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work by using `await client.fetch_member()` instead of `guild.get_member()`!

Still don't understand why `guild.get_member()` didn't work, though...

I might need it in the future and it'd be a pity if I still can't get it to work by then, but I guess this is sort of a solution for now.